# After using "del np.dtype", should re-importing numpy fix this?

Tags: python, numpy, spyder

I'm trying to understand the behavior of import in python.

I used `del numpy.dtype`, and it throws an error when I type `numpy.dtype`. But when I try to re-inport numpy, it doesn't help.

I tried to follow the answer from [Python: "de-import", "re-import", "reset import"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45301092/python-de-import-re-import-reset-import) by doing `del sys.modules['numpy']`, but I get an error when I try to import numpy again afterwards.

The weird part about all of this is that I **can** still use numpy without any issue, except that when I type `numpy.dtype`, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Can someone explain what is happening and how I can restore:

1. numpy.dtype
2. the ability to import numpy without error

I'm using Python2.7 in a Spyder interactive IPython console.

Comment: Can you not simply exit your Python session and start a new one?

Comment: The module will only get imported once, the subsequent imports don't do anything.

Comment: @Keldorn Yes, I can exit Python, but that takes some time.
@user3483203 Is this true even in the case of using ```del sys.modules['numpy']``` ?

Comment: @I_Don't_Code if you delete it from `sys.modules`, it will get reloaded the next time you import

Comment: @user3483203 Strangely, when I try to import again, it throws the error ```ImportError: cannot import name add_newdocs```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A module will only get imported once in Python, so your subsequent imports do nothing.  You can use `importlib`'s `reload` method to reload a library, which will bring `dtype` back, after you have deleted it.

---

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(numpy)

# numpy.dtype accessible again
```

You mentioned you are using Python 2.7, and the `importlib` included in 2.7 is mainly for ease of updating, and does not contain a `reload` method.  You should really update to Python 3, as 2020 is approaching fast, but you can use the builtin `reload` method if you insist.

Comment: Nice. However, does that work with python 2.7, as asked by OP? https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html says "New in version 3.1."

Comment: For python 2.7, it should just be `reload(numpy)`, builtin function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/961219/6352677

Comment: As a side question, what's happening in 2020 to Python 2.7?