# Python Debugging: Given an error, can I step backwards, fix the error, and continue the program?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

My current (PyCharm based) debugging workflow is to run a program in debug mode. When I run into an error, I fix it, and restart the program from the beginning.

Is it possible to save re-running the healthy part of the program by moving the program back by one step, fix the issue, and continue the program?

Is there a general way to do this, and one specific for PyCharm?

[edit:]
this is related but not similar to [Is there "Edit and Continue" in PyCharm? Reload code into running program like in Eclipse / PyDev?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333815/is-there-edit-and-continue-in-pycharm-reload-code-into-running-program-like-i) , as there the author anticipates halts the program before an error occurs. here, i consider an error state

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there "Edit and Continue" in PyCharm? Reload code into running program like in Eclipse / PyDev?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333815/is-there-edit-and-continue-in-pycharm-reload-code-into-running-program-like-i)

Comment: I'd say no: the author needs to place a breakpoint ahead of the potential error. 
Once in an error state, this solution will not help to fix and continue the program.
however this post is 6 years old, maybe technology advanced in that time

Comment: Well hopefully someone else has answers then, since in my research it looked like that was the most up-to-date info.